# Error with uploading images

Tags: php, image, file, upload, syntax-error

```
faultCode1faultStringWarning:move_uploaded_file(../infos/upload/photo_1-immo65luz-1415182268.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eq8115/eq79237/html/application_v2/index.php on line 75faultCode1faultStringWarning:move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/home/tmp/phpMTDMSQ' to '../infos/upload/photo_1-immo65luz-1415182268.png' in /home/eq8115/eq79237/html/application_v2/index.php on line 75modif
```

The above error is showing up when I try to add a photo in admin panel.

This is part of the code that is used for upload:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $k=>$photo){

                //---- changement de nom

                $nom_file = str_replace(".","_",$photo['name']);

                $t_nom = split("_",$nom_file);

                $ext = $t_nom[count($t_nom)-1];

                $nom = "upload/".$k."-".$_SESSION['admin']."-".time().".".$ext;

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'],"../infos/$nom"))

                {

                    $_POST[$k] = $nom;

                }

            }
```

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: check user -permission for that folder you are uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Your error string already says that your directory don't have write permission.

Check the user permission of directory if not then You have to set it as 755 permission